# Unity (error CS1061) Trying to show/hide inventory

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to hide and show the inventory

[inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqvYG.png)

but im getting this error " error CS1061: 'Canvas' does not contain a definition for 'enable' and no accessible extension method 'enable' accepting a first argument of type 'Canvas' could be found ".

(this "Canvas" on the first picture is just the crosshair)

I think I need to call the inventory for the script but I don't know how to do it.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZdPP.png)

```
    public static Inventory instance = null;
    
    private bool inventoryOpen = false;

    private void Awake(){
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        if (GetComponent<Canvas>().isActiveAndEnabled)
            GetComponent<Canvas>().enable = false;
    }

    public void ShowHide_Inventory(){
        inventoryOpen = !inventoryOpen;
        GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = inventoryOpen;
    }

    private void HandleInventory(){
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
            Inventory.instance.ShowHide_Inventory();
    }
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why hide/show the whole canvas and not just your inventory window

Comment: That's a simple **typo**: `enable` != `enabled` .. voting to close this question

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you want to use `enabled` instead of `enable` as you do in your ShowHide_Inventory method

```
if (GetComponent<Canvas>().isActiveAndEnabled)
        GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
```

Comment: OK, it worked, thank you very much, have a nice day.

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)